# Hoy do I get my data from Windows 8 back?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

I had Windows 8 installed in my HP-PC when I proceeded to install Ubuntu 14.04 to run alongside it. My PC has a 2TB hard drive where Windows 8 and all my data was installed. In order to make the Linux partition I used an external 500GB hard drive and left the 2TB one untouched, but the first time that I ran the Ubuntu installer I made the partitions (4 in total) in the external drive but had to quit due to an emergency at the time, so I reverted the partitions I had made, quit the installer and shut down the PC. 
When I turned it on again it automatically opened the GRUB where no Windows 8 option was available, as I ran the Ubuntu installer again it did not find any other OS installed which I found odd but still continued, once again I made the partitions in the external drive, leaving the PC 2TB hard drive untouched and finalized it. 
Now whenever I turn on the computer I can't access Windows 8 only Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I can still see the NTFS partitions are there because I used suds testdisk and I can see them exactly as they were before. 
My question is how can I recover Windows 8, or access it, or at least recover my data?

Comment: If your system is Windows 8, you can go into UEFI and directly boot Windows. And first make good backup of Windows and make a Windows repair flash drive. Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? How you boot installer is then how it installs. Post this above and perserve formatting. `sudo parted -l` If both are UEFI, you must turn off fast startup or always on hibernation in Windows.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu from a usb drive using BIOS boot mode. Also I ran boot-repair with the recommended repair option and got a message saying "GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag)."

Comment: You might be able to run `sudo update-grub` to fix it.

Comment: If you have Windows from a vendor, then it is UEFI. You must have booted Ubuntu in BIOS mode if it is asking for the bios_grub partition as that is only required for BIOS boot on gpt drives. But Windows only boots in UEFI mode from gpt partitioned drives. Reboot in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the installer has overwritten your bootloader.

1. Boot from the Windows 8 installer, and the first window will contain a "Repair your computer" label.
2. Then select "Advanced options" and "Command Prompt"
3. Run commands "bootrec.exe /FixBoot" and "bootrec.exe /FixMbr" to fix the bootloader
4. If it says "Element not found" then Windows partition isn't active partition anymore, so to make it active again, run the utillity "Diskpart"
5. In diskpart, type "list disk" and find your disk. It will have a number. Then to select it, type "select disk #" where # means the number you found.
6. Type "list partition" to select your partition then type "select partition #" where now # means your partition number.
7. If you selected your partition, type "active" and the partition is active again. Exit by typing "exit"
8. Now in the command prompt, type "bootrec.exe /nt60 C:" and the commands in the 3rd step just to be sure.
9. Now you should be able to boot.

Comment: Thanks, the problem with the link you provided is that it needs windows 8 to fix the problem, and the only OS I have currently access to in my computer is Ubuntu. It says that I have to use a USB or DVD windows 8 recovery media but I don't know how to get that.

Comment: Ohh, my bad. I hope it will do that: http://peter.upfold.org.uk/blog/2013/02/28/restore-windows-8-bootloader/ It's started from the installer DVD